# Print Binary Tree With Proper Spaces in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I have following code to print binary tree at each level. However I don't want the current output , I need extra spaces of pyramid like structure:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class LevelOrder 
{
static class Node
{
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
        left = null;
        right =null;
    }
}

static void printLevelOrder(Node root)
{
    if(root == null)
        return;

    Queue<Node> q =new LinkedList<Node>();

    q.add(root);            
    while(true)
    {               
        int nodeCount = q.size();
        if(nodeCount == 0)
            break;

        while(nodeCount > 0)
        {    
            Node node = q.peek();
            System.out.print("("+node.data + ")");

            q.remove();

            if(node.left != null)
                q.add(node.left);
            if(node.right != null)
                q.add(node.right);

            if(nodeCount>1){
               System.out.print(", ");
            }
            nodeCount--;    
        }     
        System.out.println();
    }
}       
public static void main(String[] args) 
{           
    Node root = new Node(6);
    root.left = new Node(3);
    root.right = new Node(2);
    root.left.left = new Node(8);
    root.left.right = new Node(9);
    root.right.right = new Node(-2);
    root.right.left = new Node(3);
    printLevelOrder(root);    
   }

}
```

My Current output is AS FOLLOWS:

```
(6)
(3), (2)
(8), (9), (3), (-2)
```

But I need something like :

```
       (6)
    (3),  (2)
 (8), (9), (3), (-2)
```

How can I print the above output with required spaces in effective way. Please help.

Comment: Keeping your current implementation (almost) the same, I don't see a way of doing this without knowing the height of the tree at the root level.

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: do a preorder traversal of the tree, root-> left->right. Also, get the depth of the tree, e.g: 2 in your case. Implement spaceing logic like for root = depth, followed by number,  level 1 -> depth-1 followed by each node at that level, level 2 = depth-1 followed by each node and so ...

Comment: I just want to clarify, your logic works but you want the format to be pretty?

Comment: @inson yes I need my format to be like pyramid structure.

Comment: in that case have you ever tried printing triangle like staircase?

Answer (score 0):

*Actually you are getting the correct output but you are not getting the output in the correct format.To do that you have to display the corresponding outputs as a triangle.I have to accomplish that with my code.If you get any problem,feel free to comment.I will surely help you out.*

**Try this code:-**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue; 
public class LevelOrder
 { 
 static class Node
 { int data; Node left; Node right;
Node(int data) 
{
this.data = data;
left = null;
right = null;
depth = 1;
}
}

static void printLevelOrder(Node root) 
{
if (root == null)
    return;

Queue < Node > q = new LinkedList < Node > ();

q.add(root);
while (true)
 {
    int nodeCount = q.size();
    if (nodeCount == 0)
        break;

    while (nodeCount > 0)
 {
        Node node = q.peek();
        System.out.print("(" + node.data + ")");

        q.remove();

        if (node.left != null)
            q.add(node.left);
        if (node.right != null)
            q.add(node.right);
        if (node.depth != null)
            System.out.print(" ");
        if (nodeCount > 1)
 {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }

        nodeCount--;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
Node root = new Node(6);
root.left = new Node(3);
root.right = new Node(2);
root.left.left = new Node(8);
root.left.right = new Node(9);
root.right.right = new Node(-2);
root.right.left = new Node(3);
printLevelOrder(root);
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you please tell where did you declare depth? I tried running your code but it did't give me pyramid like structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for, I introduced a method, to calculate the depth of the tree and based on the level at which you are printing nodes, I introduce spaces accordingly.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Main 
{
static class Node
{
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
        left = null;
        right =null;
    }
}

static int depthOfTree(Node root, int d) {
  if(root == null) {
    return d;
  }
  int left = d;
  int right = d;
  if(root.left != null) {
    left = depthOfTree(root.left, d+1);
  }
  if(root.right != null) {
    right = depthOfTree(root.right, d+1);
  }
  return Math.max(left, right);
}

static void printLevelOrder(Node root, int depth)
{
    if(root == null)
        return;

    Queue<Node> q =new LinkedList<Node>();

    q.add(root);            
    while(true)
    {               
        int nodeCount = q.size();
        if(nodeCount == 0)
            break;
        for(int i=0; i<depth; i++) {
          System.out.print("  ");
        }
        while(nodeCount > 0)
        {    
            Node node = q.peek();
            System.out.print("("+node.data + ")");

            q.remove();

            if(node.left != null)
                q.add(node.left);
            if(node.right != null)
                q.add(node.right);

            if(nodeCount>1){
               System.out.print(", ");
            }
            nodeCount--;    
        }
        depth--;
        System.out.println();
    }
}       
public static void main(String[] args) 
{           
    Node root = new Node(6);
    root.left = new Node(3);
    root.right = new Node(2);
    root.left.left = new Node(8);
    root.left.right = new Node(9);
    root.right.right = new Node(-2);
    root.right.left = new Node(3);
    int d = depthOfTree(root, 1);
    //System.out.println(d);
    printLevelOrder(root, d);    
   }

}
```

Hope this helps!